# Why is my code not printing in the debug console?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and to Visual Studio Code so I am trying to teach myself how to use the program. I primarily want to code in Java and I have it set up correctly. The problem is that every time I try to run a basic program, it prints in the terminal but in the tutorial videos it prints in debug console. Has anyone had this problem and can anyone help me fix this?

```java
/**
 * Hello
 */
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context as to what your program might consist of?

Comment: My program is just a simple hello world program. I was testing it so it's basically the first thing you ever learn in java

Comment: Are you doing something similar to this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4BTKD3iyYE (equivalent of https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) Try running it in debug mode (tap F5).

Comment: @dnunez32 i did that and i still only printed in the terminal, not the debug console

Comment: It's really hard to understand what the problem is, actually. On our side we have zero context. Maybe provide a code snippet with some screenshots?

Comment: `/**
 * Hello
 */
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}`

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add your code. Never mind, I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json** like :

```
"configurations": [
           {
             "type": "java",
             "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
             "request": "launch",
             "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
             "console": "internalConsole",
             "projectName": "my.app"
           }
         ]
```

then it will show in `Debug Console`

Comment: I don't think this to be a bad answer. It requires tho to then always run the project with this configuration and to then add this configuration to every "project" that is made. There is a solution in the vscode settings

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your settings (ctrl + , | apple-key + , | by clicking on the Wheel Icon on the bottom left -> "Settings" | ctrl+p -> type in "settings")
2. Search for "java.debug.settings.console".
3. Change your default console to "internalConsole".